# Application find a file when execute from IDE but when I execute .jar the file is not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I am compile the application with maven.
When I run the application from IDE (IntelliJ) it start and find the file, but when I use `java -jar file.jar` the application starts but can not find a file that is inside my *jar*.

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
file:/home/gustavo/projects/projectname/target/projectname.jar!/template/arq.pdf
(Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado)
```

Comment: Post the code, where you are reading the file.

Comment: File file = new File(ClassLoaders.getResource("/template/arq.pdf").getFile());

Comment: Reding via File within Java Code is simply wrong. User getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/templates/arq.pdf")....

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for the answer, but now i have other error. :(
 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@5c19b13d'
My code: 'File templatePersonalizado = new File(ClassLoaders.getResourceAsStream("/template/arq.pdf").toString());
'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem change the type of class from File file to InputStream inputStream. Thanks everyone that help me.